# Laravel 5.5 Controller@destroy DI won't inject model

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-5.5

I have resource controller with following destroy method:

```
public function destroy(ClinicImage $clinicImage)
{
    $clinicImage->delete();

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Изображение удалено');
}
```

Also I have grid with following lines:

```
<td>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group">
        <button type="button" data-url="{{route('admin.clinic-image.destroy', [$clinic->id, $image->id])}}" class="btn btn-danger">
            <i class="fa fa-remove fa-fw"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</td>
```

And finally I have function to send form on button click:

```
$('.table').find('.btn.btn-danger').click(function(){
     var form = makeForm({_method: 'DELETE'},{action: $(this).data('url')});
     form.submit();
});

function makeForm(data, options) {
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.method = 'POST';

    var token = document.createElement('input');

    token.name = '_token';
    token.value = jQuery('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

    form.appendChild(token);

    jQuery.each(data, function(key, value){
        var input = document.createElement('input');

        input.name = key;
        input.value = value;

        form.appendChild(input);
    });

    if(Object.keys(options).length) {
        jQuery.each(options, function(option, value){
            form[option] = value;
        });
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);

    return form;
}
```

When i sending form to `/admin/clinic/1/clinic-image/1`, I get following error:
`Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ClinicImageController::destroy() must be an instance of App\ClinicImage, string given`

Controller routes.
[image: my routes]

So my question is: Why DI do not recognize my route and model id?

Comment: You are sending two parameters and expection only one, try this : public function destroy($clinic, ClinicImage $clinicImage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
public function destroy($clinic, $clinicImage)
{
    $clinicImage = ClinicImage::where('id', $clinic)->where('image', $clinicImage); //I'm guessing the name of the columns.
    $clinicImage->delete();

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Изображение удалено');
}
```

Comment: Your answer partially right, I just added dependency for `Clinic $clinic`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you're using wrong argument name in the controller.

Change your signature in a controller.

Instead of `$clinicImage` change it to `$clinic_image`

***Option 1*** : Change in controller

```
public function destroy(ClinicImage $clinic_image) //$clinicImage to $clinic_image
{
    $clinicImage->delete();

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Изображение удалено');
}
```

***Option 2*** :
Change parameter in route file:

```
Route::delete('/admin/clinic/{clinic}/clinic-image/{clinicImage})->name('');
```

Comment: I can't change route parameter because controller is resource.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller file

```php
public function destroy(ClinicImage $clinicImage)
{
    $clinicImage->delete();

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Изображение удалено');
}
```

And in your view file

```html
<td>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group">
        <button type="button" data-url="{{route('admin.clinic-image.destroy', [$clinic->id])}}" class="btn btn-danger"> (over here you need to pass 1 id at a time which you need to delete)
            <i class="fa fa-remove fa-fw"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</td>
```